# How to find out what makes Linux (Gnome 44 with Wayland) sluggish?

Tags: gnome, manjaro, wayland

I noticed a couple weeks ago that my laptop got very sluggish. Most noticeably the mouse pointer would not move for a bit. Sometimes just so it looked like choppy movement, sometimes the pointer would be stuck for multiple seconds. The same behavior for typing, it would take a while between starting to type and when the letters appear. Then smooth typing for a while and then a "pause" again. Also launching and switching applications seemed to take longer than before.

My first thought was that a program is hogging memory, but it does not seem to be the case. Disabling and/or uninstalling various applications and extensions wouldn't help.

I finally just reinstalled Manjaro again. Unfortunately, the fresh install is even worse than before. I have barely any applications installed, besides the ones I really need for work. And still, even just booting and not launching any programs, the mouse pointer gets stuck and everything is sluggish.

Is there a way to troubleshot or figuring out what is causing this?

System:
Kernel: 6.1.31-2-MANJARO
GNOME 44.1
GTK 3.24.37
wm: gnome-shell
dm:
GDM: 44.1

Laptop: TUXEDO Pulse 15 Gen1
AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics and 32GB RAM